# Is Jewish orphan raised outside of Israel considered automatically as a Hebrew person?

Tags: gentiles

Would a person born of both Jewish parents, but raised in an orphanage house in another country, say, in France, and, thus, not knowing a word in Hebrew, would still be considered as a Jew by the Hebrew people?

Comment: Why do you think knowing Hebrew or being raised in Israel is a requirement for being Jewish?

Comment: The first recursive algorithm, you are Jewish if and only if you yourself have validly converted to Judaism OR your birth mother was Jewish at the time of your birth (according to this law). While someone raised like this is Jewish, he is considered a *tinok shenishbah* - an infant kidnapped and raised by idolaters.